# How does my index page need to be written in order to display data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a form that is dropdown in nature for the first time. With the help of some of you I have been successful thus far, but at this point I am creating the app/index.html.erb page:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <h2><%= @job.category %></h2>
  <p><%= @job.poster %></p>
<% end %>
```

The code above is rendering the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Jobs#index
undefined method `category' for nil:NilClass
```

I thought the code was telling me that I had nil in category which I did and so I updated category as well as others in rails console, but I continue to receive this error and I am not sure why nor how to fix it.

In my app/show.html.erb the code is similar:

```
<h1><%= @job.category %></h1>
<p><%= @job.poster %></p>
<p><%= @job.location %></p>
<p><%= @job.description %></p>

<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

and it works just fine.

This is my form partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Poster:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:poster, options_for_select([['Nick Maloney','Nick Maloney'],
        ['Peter Brown','Peter Brown'],['Jen Morris','Jen Morris']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Category:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:category, options_for_select([['Landscaping','Landscaping'],
        ['Babysitting','Babysitting'],['Tree planting','Tree planting']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Location:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:location, options_for_select([['Dorchester','Dorchester'],
        ['Roxbury','Roxbury'],['Mattapan','Mattapan']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Status:", class: 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:status, options_for_select([['New','New'],
        ['Pending','Pending'],['Complete','Complete']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.input :description, label: "Job Description" %>
  <%= f.submit 'Add Job', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

and this is my jobs_controller.rb:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @jobs = Job.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show

  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(jobs_params)

    if @job.save
      redirect_to @job, notice: 'Your job was successfully added'
    else
      render "New"
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update

  end

  def destroy

  end

  private

  def jobs_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:poster, :category, :location, :status, :description)
  end

  def find_job
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what value has `@job`, note that when you iterate over `jobs` assign a block variable called `job`, but then inside you want to get the category attribute from `@job`, the instance variable, and Rails will try to know where does that variable come from and what's the value.

Try `job.attribute`:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <h2><%= job.category %></h2>
  <p><%= job.poster %></p>
<% end %>
```

`@job` isn't available in your `index` view, because your index method has a `@jobs` variable with all the Job records. And the reason you can access `@job.category` in your show method is because you have a `@job` variable created in the private method `find_job` which is available in such method thanks the `before_action` callback setted in the second line.